# How to Sort comments to show the newest comments on top and old ones at the bottom in Express or React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on a Mern-stack Application, in my Application, I have an Event model and the event has many comments. how do I sort the comments to show the newest comments on top while the old ones will be at the bottom?

And where should I make this logic? in the API (backend) or frontend (React)? The comment have an attribute called `createdAt` a new date gets inserted into createdAt attribute anytime a comment is created.

This is how I fetch an Event with comments in my Express backend

```
router.get("/:id/eventcomments", async (req, res) => {
  const event = await Event.findById({ _id: req.params.id }).populate(
    "eventcomments"
  );
  res.json(event);
});
```

and Here is the Schema Model for comment.

```
const eventcommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
createdAt: { 
    type: Date, 
    required: true, 
    default: Date.now
},
  event: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event'}
})
```

Here is my Component

```
export default function EventAndComments(props) {
    const EventComment = (props) => (
     <CardContent>
       <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
         {props.comment.name}
       </Typography>
       <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
        {props.comment.description}
       </Typography>
    </CardContent>
  );

  const theme = useTheme();
  const [events, setEventData] = useState([]);
  const [comments, setCommentData] = useState([]);

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      maxWidth: 550,
    },
    media: {
      height: 0,

      paddingTop: "86%", // 16:9
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
   },
   expand: {
     transform: "rotate(0deg)",
     marginLeft: "auto",
     transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
     }),
   },
   expandOpen: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)",
   },
   avatar: {
     backgroundColor: red[500],
   },
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get(
      "http://localhost:9000/events/" +
        props.match.params.id +
       "/eventcomments"
     )

     .then((response) => {
       setEventData(response.data);
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, []);
 const onPageLoad = () => {
  axios
  .get(
    "http://localhost:9000/events/" +
      props.match.params.id +
      "/eventcomments"
  )

  .then((response) => {
    setCommentData(response.data.eventcomments);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
useEffect(() => {
 onPageLoad();
}, []);


 const nowIso = new Date();
 const getTitle = (startDateTs, endDateTs) => {
  const now = Date.parse(nowIso);

  if (endDateTs <= now) {
    return "Started:" + " " + moment(startDateTs).format("LLLL");
  }

  if (startDateTs < now && endDateTs > now) {
    return "Live:" + " " + moment(startDateTs).format("LLLL");
  }

    return "Starting:" + " " + moment(startDateTs).format("LLLL");
  };

  const getEnded = (startDateTs, endDateTs) => {
   const now = Date.parse(nowIso);

  if (endDateTs <= now) {
    return "Ended:" + " " + moment(startDateTs).format("LLLL");
  }

 if (startDateTs < now && endDateTs > now) {
   return "Will End:" + " " + moment(startDateTs).format("LLLL");
 }

  return "Ends:" + " " + moment(startDateTs).format("LLLL");
};

const [eventDescription, setEventComment] = React.useState("");
const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

const handleChange = (parameter) => (event) => {
  if (parameter === "name") {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }
  if (parameter === "description") {
    setEventComment(event.target.value);
  }
};

const onSubmit = useCallback(
(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:9000/events/" +
        props.match.params.id +
        "/eventcomment",
      { name: name, description: eventDescription }
    )

    .then(function (response) {
      onPageLoad();
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
  [props.match.params.id, name, eventDescription]
 );

 let eventCommentList = comments.map((comment, k) => (
   <EventComment comment={comment} key={k} />
 ));

 return (
   <Grid
    container
    spacing={0}
    direction="column"
    alignItems="center"
    justify="center"
    style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
   >
   <Card className={classes.root}>
    <h3
      style={{
        background: "   #800000",
        color: "white",
        textAlign: "center",
      }}
      className={classes.cardheader}
    >
      {events.title}
    </h3>
    <CardHeader
      avatar={
        <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
          CB
        </Avatar>
      }
      action={
        <IconButton aria-label="settings">
          <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
      }
      title={getTitle(
        Date.parse(events.startingDate),
        Date.parse(events.closingDate)
      )}
      subheader={getEnded(
        Date.parse(events.startingDate),
        Date.parse(events.closingDate)
      )}
      style={{ background: "#DCDCDC" }}
    />
    <CardMedia
      className={classes.media}
      image={events.eventImage}
      title="Paella dish"
    />
    <CardContent>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
        {events.description}
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
  </Card>

  <form
    className={classes.root}
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off"
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
  >
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="component-simple">Name</InputLabel>
      <Input
        id="component-simple"
        value={name}
        onChange={handleChange("name")}
        label="Name"
      />
    </FormControl>

    <FormControl variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Description</InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput
        id="component-outlined"
        value={eventDescription}
        onChange={handleChange("description")}
        label="Description"
      />
    </FormControl>
    <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
      Create Comment
    </Button>
  </form>
  <CardContent>{eventCommentList}</CardContent>
  </Grid>
 );
 }
}
```

I have added all my codes.

Comment: You can order at client or server, the server will be preferable as the results can be cached. lookup mongodb `sort`

Comment: I have used Mongo DB sort but it didn't work. @Samuel

Comment: @Chuckwuma - what do you mean MongoDB sort does not work? Please at least study the docs and attempt it to resolve it - SO is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` functionality in mongoose like this

```
const event = await Event.findById({ _id: req.params.id }).populate("eventcomments").sort({createdAt:-1});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort)

**Update**

Try passing it as an option

```
const event = await Event.findById({ _id: req.params.id },null,{sort:{createdAt:-1}}).populate("eventcomments")
```

Comment: I have tried this example  before but it didn't work, I also tried your code but it didn't work either. @Shivam

Comment: it still doesn't work, I really don't know why. @Shivam

Comment: The sort command is applied to the collection you're querying. You're trying to sort subdocuments in a different collection. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you don't really need the createdAt field. MongoDB ObjectIds encode the time of object creation. From the MongoDB docs:

> sorting on an _id field that stores ObjectId values is roughly equivalent to sorting by creation time.

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/bson-types/#objectid

You can also extract the timestamp from an objectId by using ObjectId.getTimestamp().

However, if you're trying to sort sub-documents, then you can't do it in a query on the parent. You're going to have to use an aggregation pipeline, since the sort command is going to sort your Events, not your comments.

In your use case though, you would be better off storing the whole comment document on the event document. Every time someone posts a comment it should get pushed into the array of comments on the event, where it will live already sorted. This will prevent your server from having to do a TON of lookups and document modifications every time someone requests an event. The way you have things set up now, your database will receive (1 * the number of comments) read requests every time someone looks up an event. Then it will have to insert those comments into your event document. This is fine in relational database systems; It's what they're designed to do. It doesn't work so well in NoSQL databases.

This is referred to as an **embedded document** pattern. And if you want to use MongoDB, then it's a very good idea to familiarize with it. Here is an in depth link where you can find more info on this pattern and its usefulness in a NoSQL system:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: I will definitely look into it to learn more about how to do it better. @Charles

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work with this code.

```
router.get("/:id/eventcomments", async (req, res) => {
  Event.findById({ _id: req.params.id })
  .populate("eventcomments", "_id name description createdAt", 
    null, {
    sort: { createdAt: -1 },
  })
 .exec(function (error, results) {
   res.json(results);
 });
});
```

the difference between what I have here and the example given above is that it requires that I pass in the names of my fields.